# codeginiter jquery post data clean url

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, url, post

Im using codeginiter as php framework and i want to do jquery post data to one of my methods..
The method is declared inside Inbox controller and its named read for example:

```
public function read($data){
 //do somethin with $data
}
```

in my javascript code i have this

```
$.post('inbox/read', { somedatahere:value}, function.....);
```

When i use this form i got this post url `www/inbox/read?somedatahere=value`
but i really wanted to be this way... `www/inbox/read/value...`

this is how could i try to solve ths problem but isn't fancy...

```
   $.post('inbox/read/' + value, {}, function.....);
```

Comment: www/inbox/read?somedatahere=value,this is not post,this is get,your problem is not here..try to find it from another place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you do a `jQuery` post, the data is not in the URL but inside the body of the request.

```
$.post('inbox/read', { url: value });
```

You can access this data in your controller as follows:

```
function read() {
   $url = $this->input->post('url');
}
```

Make sure you are loading the correct helpers and libraries. Not sure which one you have to load, I think the URL helper, but I'm not sure it's been a while since I've worked with Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
post_url = '<?=base_url()?>' + 'inbox/read';
post_data = {
   'somedatahere': status,
};
$.post(post_url, post_data, function(e){
  // todo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To augment [Dieter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857687/183254), you can also just use a regular ajax request and alter the URL

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/inbox/read/' + value,
    ...
```